# "Translating Objective-C Code to Swift: Struggling with Properties Extraction from Bookmark Data"Help me to translate this code

Tags: swift, objective-c

I'm currently working on converting a piece of code written in Objective-C to Swift, and I've encountered a bit of a roadblock. The part that's giving me trouble involves extracting properties from a bookmark data.

```
NSMutableArray *extractItems(NSString *path)
{
    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray* items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData* bookmark = nil;
    NSDictionary* properties = nil;
    
    // Extract items
    for(id object in data[@"$objects"])
    {
        // Reset bookmark
        bookmark = nil;
        
        // Extract bookmark data
        if([object isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] == YES)
        {
            bookmark = object;
        }
        
        // Extract bookmark from dictionary
        if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == YES)
        {
            bookmark = [object objectForKey:@"NS.data"];
        }
        
        // Skip if no bookmark
        if(bookmark == nil)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        // Extract properties
        properties = [NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[@"AllPropertiesKey"] fromBookmarkData:bookmark][@"AllPropertiesKey"];
        if(properties == nil)
        {
            // Skip this item
            continue;
        }
        
        // Create item
        Item *item = [[Item alloc] init];
        item.path = path;
        item.executable = properties[@"_NSURLPathKey"];
        item.type = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ItemType];
        item.user = extractUserFromPath(path);
        item.content = nil;
        
        // Use name from bundle or NSURLNameKey
        item.name = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:item.executable].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleName"];
        if(item.name.length == 0)
        {
            item.name = properties[@"NSURLNameKey"];
        }
        
        // Skip if there are issues
        if (item.name == nil || item.executable == nil)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        // Add item
        [items addObject:item];
    }
    
    return items;
}
```

The challenge I'm facing is related to the extraction of properties using the resourceValuesForKeys method and then accessing the NSURLBookmarkAllPropertiesKey dictionary within it

Comment: What is `NSURLBookmarkAllPropertiesKey` ? There's no such key. You seem to have a lot of made up keys in your code.

Comment: Showing your current Swift code might help, and printing `data` and `items` might help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```objectivec
// Extract properties
properties = [NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:@[@"AllPropertiesKey"] fromBookmarkData:bookmark][@"AllPropertiesKey"];
if(properties == nil)
{
    // Skip this item
    continue;
}
```

would be something like this:

```swift
// Extract properties
let allPropertiesKey = URLResourceKey("AllPropertiesKey")
guard let properties = NSURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [ allPropertiesKey ], fromBookmarkData: bookmark)?[allPropertiesKey] as? [URLResourceKey: Any] else {
    // Skip this item
    continue;
}
```

I think the cast at the end is correct but it really depends on what the made-up `"AllPropertiesKey"` key returns. Given the rest of your code, `[URLResourceKey: Any]` seems likely.

If that all does work, then a line like:

```objectivec
item.name = properties[@"NSURLNameKey"];
```

would become:

```swift
item.name = properties[.nameKey] as? String // or as! but write that defensively
```